# How to delete <a> tag and link text from html in java

Tags: java, html, regex, string, tags

I want to delete `<a>` tag and link text from my html.

Simple example:

```
String inputString = "<html><p>test <a href="example.com">link</a> </p></html>";
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("</?a[^>]*>", " ");
```

but it deletes only `<a>` tag

Expected output:

```
String result = "<html><p>test</p></html>";
```

Comment: 1. You should show expected output when posting such questions. 2 you should not use regex to parse html.

Comment: give [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) a try maybe?

Comment: +1 for Jsoup recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and a regular expression. Something like this,

```
String inputString = "<html><p>test "
    + "<a href=\"example.com\">link</a> </p></html>";
System.out.println(inputString);
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("\\s*<a.*</a>\\s*", "");
System.out.println(inputString);
```

Output is

```
<html><p>test <a href="example.com">link</a> </p></html>
<html><p>test</p></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike XML, oracle offers no parser for html like jaxb. But you can use external parser.

If you want to manipulate the html tag, then here you go:

http://jsoup.org/ and download the jsoup

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to remove  nodes and spaces

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("(\\s+)?<a.+?/a>(\\s+)?", "");
```